# one year rolling count of unique values by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

So I have the following dataframe:

```
Period      group     ID    
20130101     A        10
20130101     A        20
20130301     A        20
20140101     A        20
20140301     A        30
20140401     A        40

20130101     B        11
20130201     B        21
20130401     B        31
20140401     B        41
20140501     B        51
```

I need to count how many different `ID` there are by `group` in the last year. So my desired output would look like this:

```
Period      group     num_ids_last_year
20130101     A            2 # ID 10 and 20 in the last year
20130301     A            2 
20140101     A            2 
20140301     A            2 # ID 30 enters, ID 10 leaves
20140401     A            3 # ID 40 enters

20130101     B            1
20130201     B            2
20130401     B            3
20140401     B            2 # ID 11 and 21 leave 
20140501     B            2 # ID 31 leaves, ID 51 enters
```

Period is in datetime format. I tried many things along the lines of:

```
df.groupby(['group','Period'])['ID'].nunique() # Get number of IDs by group in a given period.
df.groupby(['group'])['ID'].nunique() # Get total number of IDs by group.

df.set_index('Period').groupby('group')['ID'].rolling(window=1, freq='Y').nunique()
```

But the last one isn't even possible. Is there any straightforward way to do this? I'm thinking maybe some kind of combination of `cumcount()` and `pd.DateOffset` or maybe `ge(df.Period - dt.timedelta(365)`, but I can't find the answer.

Thanks.

Edit: added the fact that I can find more than one `ID` in a given `Period`

Comment: Rolling windows require a fixed window. Neither 'M', nor 'Y' (due to leap years) is a fixed frequency. In this answer I explain how to 'normalize' your timeseries to allow rolling windows of a month: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569963/pandas-monthly-rolling-window/59677389#59677389

Comment: why is `20130101     B            1` set to 1 ? shouldnt it be 2 ? and if not, then why doesn't that logic apply to 2013 group A - `df.groupby([df['Period'].dt.year,'group'])['ID'].nunique()`

Comment: Because on `20130101` group B, there's only 1 `ID`: 11. I'm counting how many ID's there are from 20120101 to 20130101 in this case. What I'm counting is on a 1-year window from today, how many different ID's there are by group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at your data structure, I am guessing you have ***MANY duplicates***, so start with dropping them. `drop_duplicates` tend to be fast

I am assuming that `df['Period']` columns is of dtype `datetime64[ns]`

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
results = dict()
for start in df['Period'].drop_duplicates():
    end = start.date() - relativedelta(years=1)
    screen = (df.Period <= start) & (df.Period >= end)  # screen for 1 year of data
    singles = df.loc[screen, ['group', 'ID']].drop_duplicates()  # screen for same year ID by groups
    x = singles.groupby('group').count()
    results[start] = x
results = pd.concat(results, 0)


results
                  ID
           group    
2013-01-01 A       2
           B       1
2013-02-01 A       2
           B       2
2013-03-01 A       2
           B       2
2013-04-01 A       2
           B       3
2014-01-01 A       2
           B       3
2014-03-01 A       2
           B       1
2014-04-01 A       3
           B       2
2014-05-01 A       3
           B       2
```

is that any faster?

p.s. if `df['Period']` is not a datetime:

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'],format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Sadly there are no Period-ID duplicates, so this might take a long time. I'll try it anyways in case it's faster than I expect.

Comment: @JuanC you said that there was a total of 77 period which is managable in a loop. the duplicates I am trying to exclude is the ID - group combination as fast as possible, good luck!

Comment: Aaaaahm yes! It would be 77 groupby operations, which might be around ~40 minutes, so not bad. Do you know if this would be faster to run this on `dask`?

Comment: @JuanC sorry not sure if dask would be a better approach

Comment: No problem, when I have time I'll try both. Thanks, anyways !

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution using `groupby` and `rolling`. Note: your desired ouput counts a year from `YYYY0101` to next year `YYYY0101`, so you need rolling `366D` instead of `365D`

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Period, format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.set_index('Period')

df_final = (df.groupby('group')['ID'].rolling(window='366D')
                                     .apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).size, raw=True)
                                     .reset_index(name='ID_count')
                                     .drop_duplicates(['group','Period'], keep='last'))

Out[218]:
   group     Period  ID_count
1      A 2013-01-01       2.0
2      A 2013-03-01       2.0
3      A 2014-01-01       2.0
4      A 2014-03-01       2.0
5      A 2014-04-01       3.0
6      B 2013-01-01       1.0
7      B 2013-02-01       2.0
8      B 2013-04-01       3.0
9      B 2014-04-01       2.0
10     B 2014-05-01       2.0
```

**Note**: On 18M+ rows, I don't think this solution will make it at 10 mins. I hope it would take about 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df.sort_values(by=['Period'], inplace=True) # if not already sorted

# create new output df
df1 = (df.groupby(['Period','group'])['ID']
       .apply(lambda x: list(x))
       .reset_index())
df1['num_ids_last_year'] = df1.apply(lambda x: len(set(df1.loc[(df1['Period'] >= x['Period']-relativedelta(years=1)) & (df1['Period'] <= x['Period']) & (df1['group'] == x['group'])].ID.apply(pd.Series).stack())), axis=1)
df1.sort_values(by=['group'], inplace=True)
df1.drop('ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't answer this before. This seems to be too slow for my need, been running the `df1` line for about 20 minutes and it hasn't finished yet, which isn't possible for what I'm doing, sadly !

Comment: 1 hour later it is still running, so it's sadly definitely a no